# Float value retrieved wrong from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, double

I have a sql table. There is a float field in it. I made a model using entity framework wizard and it is represented as Double? in that model. Everything is fine to this point.

However when i retrieve value of that float field using linq to sql it gives me wrong value.

I write 0,06 to value of that float field using SQL Management Studio. But i get 0.059999999999999998 not 0,06

What is the reason. How can i correct it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: If you need exact representation go for `decimal`

Comment: you can have the same with decimal, you'll just have more decimal digits. It might be useful to use money data type